# Books for Restful webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I want to lean Restful web services In java. Can you please advise me

1. Best Books of Restful web services
2. Good Framework for Restful web services

Thanks

Comment: response.sendRedirect("www.google.com");

Comment: i don't think google is down... ;)

Comment: FYI. very simple for understanding basics... http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-documentation/1.4/jersey-documentation-1.4-user-guide.pdf

Comment: String[] books = request.getParamterValues("Restful book");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good framework with RESTful services, you can get your hand dirty with [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)